# Me sale un error al utilizar el metodo put en postman

Tags: visual-studio, phpmyadmin, postman

**Warning**:  Undefined array key "id" in **C:\xampp\htdocs\practica0\index01.php** on line **103**

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\practica0\index01.php: 106
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\practica0\index01.php(106): mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM i...')
#1 {main
}
  thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\practica0\index01.php** on line **106**

Comment: Esto tiene poco que ver con postman y mucho que ver con el código que está en `index01.php`. Si tu lo escribiste, revisa el código, si no, repórtale el error a quién haya escrito el script.